# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults') in creating Fancybox

Tags: javascript, prestashop

I did add javascript for creating fancybox from the page, it did create but not to all what needed to do and have this error. This is my HTML code

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>

            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <script src="/modules/newmodule/views/js/new.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <a href="{$link->getPageLink('contact')}?content_only=1" id="contact-us-popup">Contact us</a>
```

this is javascript code

(function(jQuery) {
jQuery(document).ready(function()  {

```
        jQuery('#contact-us-popup').fancybox({
            type: 'ajax',
            autoDimensions: false,
            autoSize: false,
            width: 600,
            height: "auto"
        });
})
```

})(jQuery.noConflict());

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research .  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the syntax was correct, but if you want to use `$link` variable, **please make sure it is valid.** 
The only php variable I can see here is `$link->getPageLink('contact')`

 Try to check `$link` with isset function **or** check the valid of `$link->getPageLink('contact')` if it is not valid, replace the href value with "#"